# postgres database logical replication: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_unique_key"

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

i am trying to set up master/slave postgres replication.
i have 2 servers, master with populated data ,i did complete backup of the database i want to replicate and restored it   in slave, then i  configured the replication with (copy_data=false) . when insert a new row in any table, it works fine, but when i do  update an existing row, i get the error:

```
022-03-16 22:29:08.708 UTC [625449] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_unique_key"
2022-03-16 22:29:08.708 UTC [625449] DETAIL:  Key (userid, classid)=(4556, 4507) already exists.
2022-03-16 22:29:08.711 UTC [625285] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 625449) exited with exit code 1
```

The table has primary key and set to "not null". My question is , how do i setup logical replication, with UPDATE statement possible ?

Comment: What was the update?  Would doing that update directly on the replica also cause that problem?

Comment: Yes, this needs more information.

Comment: no, i was doing update on master!